# How to implement artificial neural network by using php language

Tags: php, neural-network

I currently developing a system to check the eligibility to donate blood. User need to answer some question in this system. The result of donor's eligibility is base on their answer in this system. How can I implement neural network to determine the eligibility to donate blood using PHP language?

These are simple codes for my system. I reduce the question to five(5). The original that I develop has 40 question. Your respond is very appreciated. Thanks and have a nice day

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <table>

            <tr>
                <th>1.</th>
                <td>Are you healthy today?</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">Yes</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>2.</th>
                <td>Do you have any contagious disease?</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">Yes</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>3.</th>
                <td>Have you donate blood before?</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">Yes</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0">No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>4.</th>
                <td>Is there any of your family members have contagious disease?</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="1">Yes</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>5.</th>
                <td>Have you have sex before?</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="1">Yes</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="0">No</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit answer</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You would need to have some form of criteria to determine this - something which we(or at least I) know very little about and unable to answer with the current information.

Comment: You could start by writing code for that. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

With PHP I think it is impossible but using some framework or other language like python in TensorFlow it is possible, I suggest classification data work fine instead of neural network because by classification you can classify your form data with your dataset created and predict you data form with dataset which blood dontor are eligible.
create your own dataset of eligible blood donator classify by your 40 questions form that make possible for your project. I provide some link to get started. good luck.

https://scikit-learn.org/
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub